# How to ensure launching a single SQL process for more requests?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL stored procedure is called to extract the data from more sources. It takes some time to get and process the data (like minutes). The procedure should be started on demand (user action). That is, it is not to be launched periodically using the SQL Agent Job.

From the stored-procedure point of view... Is there any mechanism to check that the procedure was already launched and it is still running?

The question is related to the [How to implement the application-specific scheduler of SQL data processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64444908/1346705) However, that question is focused on creating the table with scheduled events. This question is more about possible alternatives.

**Update:** When deciding whether the stored procedure runs or not, I need to take into account also whether it was launched with the same values of parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if stored procedure is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846306/check-if-stored-procedure-is-running)

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu: Possibly yes, I have to check, if I can use it. I will update the question -- I need to take the procedure argument values into account.

Comment: The easiest way we've found is by writing to a log table when starting/stopping and within the procedure (or calling code) check if the procedure is running or not.

Comment: You can create SQL Server jobs through agent without scheduling. And let users start the job from there so that the user actions are logged and does not need user persistence (in case of connection failures, procedure continues to run).

Comment: on the other hand, using log table is also an option. you can also use both log table and SQL server Agent Jobs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472377/how-can-i-make-sql-server-2019-pretend-that-a-stored-proc-is-in-progress/62473225#62473225

Comment: Thanks to all for the hints. Actually, I am currently calling the procedure using a job scheduled each 5 minutes (and the solution seems to be good enough to be used for future). I was rather curious how to do that without SQL Server Agent -- for example when you use the Express edition of MS SQL Server. Anyway, I like the misusing of unscheduled jobs launched explicitly at the event.